# Committing daemon or service

Tags: svn, queue, daemon

I want to have a service on linux that somehow accepts requests on subversion operations.

Example of operations queue is something like this:

```
commit ~/repo/1.txt
add ~/repo/2.txt
commit ~/repo/2.txt
```

Communication through files, pipes or HTTP would be great. It seems that I'll have to write this thing myself, but may be there's already something similar. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You get svnserve with your svn distribution. That does that over a proprietary protocol. For svn access over http you need to configure apache with the the svn plugin.

This is all well described in the manual: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.html